# Returning a value of std::map via param index within a const function

Tags: c++

Is there a way to pass an std::map index as a param on a const function?

```
const SurfaceProperties &  SurfacePropertiesImpl::getSurfaceProperties(const std::string entityId) const
{
    return mSurfaceProperties[entityId];
}
```

--

```
 error: passing ‘const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, SurfaceProperties>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     return mSurfaceProperties[entityId];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `at` which is const contrary to `operator[]`

```
const SurfaceProperties&
SurfacePropertiesImpl::getSurfaceProperties(const std::string entityId) const
{
    return mSurfaceProperties.at(entityId);
}
```

It will throws if key is not found.